# How to Stop "Spring Boot Language Server"?

Tags: spring-tool-suite, spring-tools-4

For STS 4

```
Spring Tool Suite 4 

Version: 4.19.1.RELEASE
Build Id: 202308011926
Revision: 0b848aa029fb3bb6bbcbc20e22469ed4dc0241f0
```

In the IDE itself `Spring Boot Language Server` is always running or doing something. Therefore in the bottom-right always appears the following:

[image]

Even if is opened the `Progress` view and `Spring Boot Language Server` is stopped manually it remains running

[image]

Even through:

- `Preferences` -> `Language Servers`

with the options available I couldn't find something to stop it

**NOTE**

It seems due this situation, rosen the following problem: it is **not** possible apply autocompletion - <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>

Comment: This is hard to solve without knowing what exactly is going on inside of the language server process. I would recommend to enable the logging to the console view (`Preferences -> Language Servers -> Spring Language Server`, then check `Logging to Console`. This will output information from inside of the language server to the console view in Eclipse. You could also capture a few thread dumps of the language server process (using `jps` and `jstack`) to provide additional information and maybe attach all that to a new GitHub issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues

Comment: Thanks for the reply - It will be done soon - is there an official tutorial to use this feature?

Comment: Which feature specifically? The language server on its own is not a feature, but it provides a number of features, see the user guide at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/wiki/

Comment: @MartinLippert I have the same problem, but activating console logging doesn't reveal anything. After some output about reconciling various projects, console output stops, but the Spring Boot Language Server keeps running (and blocking autocompletion).

Comment: @Hok see the provided answer

Comment: I would like to mention that we fixed a number of issues under the hood here in the latest 4.20.0 release, so please update to that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the "workaround" is doing the following steps in the IDE according the cases:

```
Progress View
 Stop the "Spring Boot Language Server" to cancel
```

If it does not stop do:

```
Preferences
 Spring
  OpenRewrite
   Uncheck the "Reconciling of Java Sources" checkbox
```

Then again

```
Progress View
 Stop the "Spring Boot Language Server" to cancel
```

If it does not work, **restart** the IDE. I do this process in 2 Machines and work.

**Special Case**

```
Preferences
 Spring
   Uncheck the "Start Language Server at startup if Spring Boot is a dependency" checkbox
```

Comment: I would like to mention that we fixed a number of issues under the hood here in the latest 4.20.0 release, so please update to that. And the Reconciling preference has moved to the `Validation` section of the Spring preferences, but since it is a totally new implementation, it is hopefully not the source of trouble anymore.